# What game is this red-haired Mario character from?

Tags: game-identification, mario-series

In the Glove and Boots video [*What Happened to Pauline?*](https://youtu.be/Vyi8w9tlcj0), at 1:28 there's an image of a of red-haired girl in a white dress playing volleyball.

She's placed below a photo of Toadette and Rosalina, and just above the [Banana Fairy](http://donkeykong.wikia.com/wiki/Banana_Fairy) from Donkey Kong 64.

[image: Screenshot of mystery character]

Who is this mystery character and what game is she from?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63723/discussion-on-question-by-steven-vascellaro-what-game-is-this-red-haired-mario-c).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That is the [White Mage](https://www.mariowiki.com/White_Mage) from the Final Fantasy series.

She shows up as a playable character in Mario Sports Mix and Mario Hoops 3-on-3.

[image: White Mage]

Comment: @cde Wow, I never realized that was hair.  Thought it was just a fringe on the robes.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom You can see there IS a fringe on the hood in this image, so when it's pulled up over her head, there may not be any hair visible.  Given the indistinct nature of the 8-bit image, I think you could reasonably argue either hair or fringe depending on which you prefer.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom nope, the white mage robes in the original releases did not have a fringe on the robe hood, and when they change to the next job, White Wizard, remove their hood. Still a red head.

Comment: @steve-o White Mage evolves into White Wizard. No hood, still a red head. The NES version is a Redhead, the Playstation and GBA turned her blonde. Only the PSP version has red triangles on the hood. See http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/White_Mage_(Final_Fantasy)

Comment: Her Mario Sports Mix icon clearly shows that its hair too. It's inside the shaded part of the hood. https://www.mariowiki.com/images/thumb/8/88/WhiteMagePureWhite.png/469px-WhiteMagePureWhite.png

Comment: @Steve-O The sprite for when she's at low health makes it more obvious it's hair. As a side note, there's a good chance the only reason they used red for her hair is because of the NES's color limitations. The Fighter and Red Mage's hair colors also match a different part of their sprite, and the Fighter's hair color also changed in later versions of the game.